# use variable value as format name

Tags: sas

I have already defined `fmtA` and `fmtB`.

fmtA

1->1

2->2

fmtB

1->2

2->4

Input data:

```
x format y
1 fmtA   
1 fmtB
2 fmtA
3 fmtA
```

I try to format column `x` to `y` based on column `format`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the `putn` function, e.g.:

```
proc format;
value fmtA
1 = 1
2 = 2
;
value fmtB
1 = 2
2 = 4
;
run;

data have;
input x format $;
cards;
1 fmtA   
1 fmtB
2 fmtA
3 fmtA
;
run;

data want;
set have;
y = putn(x,format);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

The PUTN and PUTC functions allow you to apply a format at DATA step run time. Try:

```
y=putn(x, cats(format,'.')) ;
```